HtmlWebpackPlugin: trying to add a script in existing index.html
In webpack.config.ts using HtmlWebpackPlugin as -
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'IndexFile/index.html',
            // inject: 'body',
            templateParameters: {
                customScript: `<script src="myscript.js"></script>`
            }
        })

In index.html, I have -
<body>
    <%= customScript %>
</body>

I'm noticing that the variable is not getting updated. Am I doing anything wrong?

Instead of html-webpack-plugin you can use the modern powerful html-bundler-webpack-plugin.
All script and style source files (js, ts, css, scss, etc.) can be specified directly in the HTML template using <script> and <link> tags.
The plugin resolves source files of assets in templates and replaces them with correct output URLs in the generated HTML.
The resolved assets will be processed via Webpack plugins/loaders and placed into the output directory.
Using the bundler plugin:

An entry point is an HTML template.
Binding the source script/style filenames directly in HTML using <script> and <link>.
Resolving source asset files specified in attributes href src srcset etc.
Inline JS, CSS, SVG, PNG without additional plugins and loaders.
Support for any templating engine (Eta, EJS, Handlebars, Nunjucks, LiquidJS, etc.).

For example, there is the HTML template:
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- relative path to SCSS source file -->
    <link href="../scss/style.scss" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- relative path to TypeScript source file -->
    <script src="../app/main.js" defer="defer"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <!-- relative path to image source file -->
    <img src="../assets/images/picture.png" />
  </body>
</html>

Minimal Webpack config:
const path = require('path');
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: {
        index: 'src/views/index.html', // save generated HTML into dist/index.html
      },
      js: {
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js', // JS output filename
      },
      css: {
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css', // CSS output filename
      },
    }),
  ],
  
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ico|png|jp?g|svg)/,
          type: 'asset/resource',
        },
      ],
    },
};

The generated HTML contains hashed output URL of assets:
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/style.1234abcd.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/main.ab32dc41.js" defer="defer"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <img src="ab12cd34.png" />
  </body>
</html>

